# Showing $\langle \frac{\partial b(v)}{\partial t}, v \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1(\Omega)} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}\Psi^*(b(v))$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, convex-analysis

Let $b$ be continuous and increasing with $b(0) = 0$. Define $\Psi(t) = \int_0^t b(s)\;ds$ and $\Psi^*(s) = \sup_{r \in \mathbb{R}} (sr-\Psi(r))$.

(Note $\Psi^*(b(s)) + \Psi(s) = sb(s)$).

> Let $v \in L^2(0,T;H^1_0(\Omega))$ with $\frac{\partial b(v)}{\partial t} \in L^2(0,T;H^{-1}(\Omega))$. Then
>   $$\langle \frac{\partial b(v)}{\partial t}, v \rangle_{H^{-1}(\Omega), H^1(\Omega)} = \frac{d}{dt}\int_{\Omega}\Psi^*(b(v)).$$

This result follows by (the more general) Lemma 1.5 of the famous *Quasilinear Elliptic-Parabolic Differential Equations* paper by Alt and Luckhaus. The authors prove it by discretising in time.

Does anyone know an alternative proof (where no discretisation is used)? Using density of smooth functions does not help. Let us assume $b$ and $b^{-1}$ are differentiable if necessary.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid time discretization?

Comment: Fro smooth $b$ and $v$'s you have by standard properties of the Legendre transform $\Psi^*$ that $<\partial_t b(v)\cdot v>=\partial_t \Psi^*(v)$. Here the dot denotes the euclidean scalar product and this also holds if $b,v$ are vector-valued. Why doesn't approximation help?

Comment: @leomonsaingeon Suppose I approximate $b(v)$ by functions $b_n \in L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^1(0,T;L^2)$ or even $C_c^\infty([0,T];H^1)$. I will get an expression involving $\int(b^{-1})'(b_n)b_n'b_n - \frac{d}{dt}\int\Psi(b^{-1}(b_n))$. I can't take the derivative inside the brackets because the integrand needs to be in $L^2(0,T;H^1) \cap H^1(0,T;H^{-1})$ at least. But the it's not (eg. can't show that the gradient is in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ after using chain rule).

Comment: ..I don't want to use density of functions defined on $Q=(0,T)\times\Omega$, I would rather use Bochner space. Maybe something like $C^1(0,T;C^1(\Omega))$ is dense in the desired space or something..

Comment: @MarkPeletier I don't like discretisation and I think it's not necessary for something simple like this identity

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question or if you already said it, but either I didn't understand or it wasn't addressed. leo monsaingeon suggested taking smooth $b$ and $v$'s. If you assume $b$ is differentiable, why can't we just take smooth approximations of $v$? I don't understand what fails in this case.

Comment: @k3thomps I think you are right. No need to apologise, it is my fault for not being clear. I wanted to avoid using results (eg. density results) on the product domain $(0,T)\times\Omega$ and wanted a purely Bochner approach. Nevertheless now it does not matter too much. I will think on your answer.